# Check if list of entities already exist in Database using linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a list of entities coming from an external source. I need to compare it to what I already have, and only add the ones that don't exist. Pseudo code below.

```
 var newVersions = item.Versions
      .Where(s => db.ExistingVersions
           .Select(t=>t.versionID)
           .DoesNotContains(s.versionID));
```

That obviously doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I don't want to use a for loop because I believe that would mean I would have hundreds of database hits just to check the versions on each item. I am loading multiple items, each item has as many as 100 versions.

Comment: Rewrite DoesNotContains as another where clause? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Not sure how to do that to exclude the existing results?

Comment: I'll wait for a few more minutes, if nobody dropped an answer I'll try something :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's nothing more to the question than I think, then it shouldn't be complicated.

Assuming that `VersionID` is unique identifier, then you can do this:

```
var existingVersions = db.ExistingVersions.Select(x => x.VersionID).ToList();
```

mind you, for `Contains` it would be better to:

```
var existingVersions = new HashSet(db.ExistingVersions.Select(x => x.VersionID).ToList());
```

**[EDIT]:** Per Magnus's comment, you can drop the `ToList` from above code snippet.

and then:

```
var newVersions = items.Versions.Where(x => !existingVersions.Contains(x.VersionID));
```

This is probably the most performant, 'cause when calling the database, you select only the `VersionID`. Other option involves writing a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) and using [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx), but you'd have to pull everything from the DB which may be more costly.

Comment: Yes, HashSet is the way to go, but you should drop the unnecessary `ToList`. (The hashset will materialize the query)

Comment: @Magnus Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited the answer to include that information.

Comment: @Magnus Why is it better to use a `HashSet`?

Comment: What if there are alot of records in database like 1M? Would `var existingVersions = new HashSet(db.ExistingVersions.Select(x => x.VersionID));` this query take long time to execute?

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
// in memory: get list of potential version ids
var potentialIds = item.Versions.Select( o => o.versionID ).ToList();

// hit database ( once ) : get existing version ids
var existingIds = db.ExistingVersions
  .Where( o => potentialIds.Contains( o.versionID ) )
  .Select( o => o.versionID )
  .ToList();

// in memory: filter potential objects
var newVersions = item.Versions
  .Where( o => !existingIds.Contains( o.versionID ) )
  .ToList();

// database inserts:
foreach( var newVersion in newVersions )
{
  ...
```

One thing to bear in mind is that this is not thread-safe: if something else is adding `ExistingVersion` rows at the same time, you may try to insert a record that was added after you checked the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async Task<bool> IsExistBy(List<int> ids, CancellationToken ct)
{
   var temp  = await _repository.TableNoTracking.Where(x=>ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToListAsync(ct);
   return temp.Count == ids.Count;
}
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.